# **Tensor field and divergence $\nabla.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, tensors, fluid-dynamics

> Let $A$ be continuously differentiable second-order tensor field defined as follows:
> A=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}&A_{12}&A_{13}\\A_{21}&A_{22}&A_{23}\\A_{31}&A_{32}&A_{33}\end{bmatrix}
> the divergence in cartesian coordinate system is a first-order tensor field and can be defined as:\begin{bmatrix}{\dfrac {\partial A_{11}}{\partial x_{1}}}+{\dfrac {\partial A_{12}}{\partial x_{2}}}+{\dfrac {\partial A_{13}}{\partial x_{3}}}\\{\dfrac {\partial A_{21}}{\partial x_{1}}}+{\dfrac {\partial A_{22}}{\partial x_{2}}}+{\dfrac {\partial A_{23}}{\partial x_{3}}}\\{\dfrac {\partial A_{31}}{\partial x_{1}}}+{\dfrac {\partial A_{32}}{\partial x_{2}}}+{\dfrac {\partial A_{33}}{\partial x_{3}}}\end{bmatrix}

A)**What is meant by 1st and 2nd order tensor?**

B)**And a second question is that I am little confused in general about $divU$, where $U$ is a vector or matrix, what shall be the nabla operator? i.e is it a column vector or a row vector? And how $divU$ is expressed in the two cases:
1)U is a matrix
2)U is a vector.**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Google "covariant derivative".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A) A first order tensor can be represented by a vector. A second order tensor can be represented as a matrix.

B) **The divergence of a matrix $A$ is a vector**, given by the formule you wrote which can be written

$$div(A)=\begin{bmatrix}{ \nabla \cdot A_{1} \\ \nabla \cdot A_{2} \\ \nabla \cdot A_{3} } \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}{\dfrac {\partial A_{11}}{\partial x_{1}}}+{\dfrac {\partial A_{12}}{\partial x_{2}}}+{\dfrac {\partial A_{13}}{\partial x_{3}}}\\{\dfrac {\partial A_{21}}{\partial x_{1}}}+{\dfrac {\partial A_{22}}{\partial x_{2}}}+{\dfrac {\partial A_{23}}{\partial x_{3}}}\\{\dfrac {\partial A_{31}}{\partial x_{1}}}+{\dfrac {\partial A_{32}}{\partial x_{2}}}+{\dfrac {\partial A_{33}}{\partial x_{3}}}\end{bmatrix}$$
where $A_i$ stand for the line $i$ of $A$ and $\nabla =(\partial_1, \partial_2, \partial_3)^t$.

The divergence of **a vector $U=( u_1,_2,u_3)^t$ is a real**, given by

$$div(U) = \nabla \cdot U= \partial_1 U_1 + \partial_2 U_2 + \partial_3 U_3$$

Comment: Sorry but if $A_i$ is a row of $A$,then its size is let's say $1×3$, so how could we multiply $\nabla.A_i$, where $\nabla$ size is $3×1$, the result will be $3×3$ matrix! (in the each row)

Comment: $\cdot$ notation is the scalar product, so you have to use it on vector of the same shape. It is linked to the usual matrixe product this way : $$U \cdot V = U^t V$$ for $U$ and $V$ two "Row" vector ( $3 \times 1$). For the $\nabla$ operator, do not forget that $"\nabla"$ is just a notation/convention used to simplify writting equations, so you can choose to see it as a $1 \times 3$ or $3 \times 1$, it doesn't matter as long as your notation are coherent and yield results of the good "size".

Comment: Concretely in my answer, you can choose $\nabla = (\partial_1, \partial_2, \partial_3)$ rather than $\nabla = (\partial_1, \partial_2, \partial_3)^t$ if you prefere.